# Какой запрос для изменения базы данных в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Как из всех ячеек *tags* скопировать первый символ и заменить символ в ячейке *symbol*.
Если посмотреть на картинку то нужно заменить в поле *symbol*
 G на H , M на L ,G на M   и т.д

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UPDATE table_name SET symbol = SUBSTRING(tags, 1, 1)`

Где `table_name` - название таблицы

Описание функции `SUBSTRING` - http://www.mysql.ru/docs/maryan/#substring

Comment: Спасибо! А что за что в этом коде отвечает? Можно где нибудь почитать?

Comment: @СергейЛапшин `SUBSTRING` - http://www.mysql.ru/docs/maryan/#substring